# why does python script fail when used with vb and the windows task scheduler?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

The script "alerts.vbs":

`Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\Anaconda2\\python.exe C:\\folder\\alerts.py",10,True`

Python script "alerts.py" (python 2.7):

`logdir='//servername/path/folder/'`

`logfiles = sorted([ f for f in os.listdir(logdir) if f.startswith('tms_int_calls-')])`

The above currently only works when I run the python script in spyder or the vbscript directly. When I run it though the windows Task Scheduler, then it crashes on the line above this paragraph "*sorted(...*" . The task scheduler is set to run it as user SYSTEM, highest privileges and "hidden" is not checked.

What I've tried :

1. Initially, I set all paths to direct paths
2. Tried creating the task with another user
3. I made sure actions set correctly within Task Scheduler
4. Tried running the task with a different username
5. Tried different OS configuration options in Task Scheduler

I think it might have something to do with permissions...

Log file when run with vbs or directly within spyder :

```
20160427155829 ...start 
20160427155829 ...imported modules 
20160427155835 ...ran php 
20160427155835 ...begin sort locate 
20160427155835 ...done sort locate 
20160427155835 ...begin sort locate 
20160427155835 ...done sort locate 
20160427155835 ...file open is : tms_int_calls-20160426161451-1098499292.csv 
20160427155836 ...sent email 
20160427155836 ...complete !
```

When run with task scheduler

```
20160427155850 ...start  
20160427155850 ...imported modules
20160427155857 ...ran php  
20160427155857 ...begin sort locate
```

Comment: How does the python crash?  Please supply any error messages and traceback.

Comment: well, it doesn't exactly crash... it just stops on that line. Since it's run as another user, I don't see any display. I made a logfile that logs where the script fails. I placed a marker before that line and after the line. It only logs before the line. I will update the initial question with the log file data.

Comment: Accessing the share on the server may require cached logon credentials. Have you tried running the task as an administrator with highest privileges? If you need the SYSTEM account, try manually setting the credentials via `subprocess.call(r'net use \\server\share /user:USERNAME PASSWORD')`.

Comment: @eryksun  : that worked perfectly, thanks a lot !